# Google Analytics Content Experiments: Session Based or User-Based?

Tags: google-analytics, google-experiments, content-experiments

I've set up a few experiments with Google Analytics using its experiment interface and everything seems to be working fine, but I haven't been able to find the answer to how Google Analytics attributes reached goal to the variations, is the attribution **session-based** or **user-based**?

Here's a scenario:

1. User visits one of the page variations included in the experiment during a session, does something else on the website and closes it.
2. The next day the user comes back, opens my website in the same browser and completes the goal (without visiting the experiment variation page)

The question is: will the reached goal still be attributed to the variation page the user saw during the previous session or will it be discarded and won't be attributed to any of the variations, since the user didn't see the variation in the same session he completed the goal.

Answer (score 1):

The reached goal should still be attributed to the variation page:

> A user is considered part of an experiment once he or she has seen the
>   experiment page. For example, if a user sees the experiment page, then
>   comes back the next day, the second visit is counted, even if the user
>   does not view the experiment page again.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6112437#